# TFS : Send mail to user if work item or comments are not provided

Tags: tfs, checkin

We have TFS 2012 installed.

I want to enforce check-in policies (Code Reviewer name, Work Item association and Comments) for each check-in.

All these settings are performed and are working fine. But still users have option to override the settings and check-in.

I want to setup email alerts so that whenever user check-ins without filling all check-in policies, there must a mail sent to user.

I tried Event subscription Tool and TFS mail alert options but both of them work for current user.

We have more than 200 employees and I cant ask each of them to subscribe for mails.

Is it possible to write custom code or some tool available which will be triggered when user check-ins overriding policies and send a mail to user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found solution. [TFS Plugin Suite](https://tfspluginsuite.codeplex.com/) This plugin is really awesome. Once the plugin is in-place, it will be called before check-in and will validate the required fields and block check-in unless all values are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a TeamAlert for CheckIn events where Policy Override Comment is not empty and Commiter = [Me]. This will sent a mail to the developer that checked in overriding the policies.

Another option is to write an EventHandler plugin for TFS, which completely denies checkins that try to override the policies.